# Laravel eloquent error execute query without where

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

If I run this query:

```
DB::table('test')
    ->update(['duma' => 'abc'])
    ->where('id', 1);
```

Laravel throws an error:

```
Call to a member function where() on int
```

But the test table all rows duma column updates with 'abc'

It seems despite the error, Laravel executes the update query without where clause. It's very dangerous.

Is that okay?

Comment: Move the `where` above the `update`. `where` returns a query builder that `update` can use, but `update` returns a count that `where` cannot use.

Comment: It is very important that you read the documentation and use a good IDE. `update` updates whatever you are sending, but it executes the statement, so if you want to update defining a `where`, you must use the `where` first and then `update`. Read the documentation please

Comment: I know the solution is move the where above the update. My question is: why executes any query if an error occurs? I think this is unacceptable.

Comment: Because it's already executed the query by the time the error happens. `->update()` executes the query, and returns the count. So the next line becomes `100->where()` which throws the error. If you break apart the query, `DB::table()->update()->where()` becomes `(query builder)->update()->where()` because `DB::table` returns a query builder, then `(int)->where()` because `update()` returns an int.

Comment: PHP, and most programming languages, run lines one by one, left to right, from top to bottom. Your code is `DB::table()->update()->where()`. This runs `DB::table()` , which sets the Table you want to update, then `->update()`, which ***immediately triggers the query***, then `->where()`, which fails, since `->update()` returns an integer of the number of rows updated. SQL runs codes in blocks, which is why `UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE ...` works. If SQL was dependent on ordering for _everything_, it would be such a pain... I get why you wrote it this way, but yeah, read the docs and use an IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add `where()` clause plz move it before the `update()`.

##### Question raised in comment

> My question is: why executes any query if an error occurs? I think this is unacceptable

basically what that query doing current is, your `update()` method updating the all records of your table instead of single record ***(expected behaviour)*** then a Boolean value `1 or 0` coming to `where()` clause, so that's why it throwing  `Call to a member function where() on int` error.

##### What will happened when move `where()` brefore `update()`?

when you moved `where()` clause before `update()` method then it will becomes part of your `eloquent query` and it will prepend a `mysql where clause` in you query. By this way before updating `mysql` will filter out those records which follows your `conditions` and then updates only those particular records.